# ¿Cómo integrar composer con namespaces?

Tags: php, mvc, namespace

Estoy creando una web a modo de prueba programada en php mediante Modelo Vista Controlador utilizando un controlador central y he integrado composer para trabajar con su autoload y no tener que incluir cada archivo manualmente. También estoy utilizando namespaces en cada directorio.

Aquí me surgen varios problemas y una duda:

- Si tengo el siguiente código donde hay un archivo `Index.php` que llama al método main() del controlador central.

```html
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Src\Libs\FrontController;

FrontController::main();
```

Y tengo el controlodor central llamado `FrontController.php`:

```html
<?php
namespace Src\Libs;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Src\Controllers\IndexController;

class FrontController{
    
    public static function main(){

        if(isset($_GET['controller'])){
            $controllerName = $_GET['controller'];
        }else{
            $controllerName = "IndexController";
        }

        if(isset($_GET['action'])){
            $actionName = $_GET['action'];
        }else{
            $actionName = "index";
        }

/*
        if (!is_callable(array($controllerName, $actionName)))
        {
            trigger_error ($controllerName . '->' . $actionName . ' no existe', E_USER_NOTICE);
            return false;
        }else{
*/
            
            $controller = new $controllerName();
            $controller->$actionName();     
    }
}
```

Que a se encarga de cargar `IndexController.php`:

```html
<?php
namespace Src\Controllers;

class IndexController{

    public function __construct(){
        require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
        require_once "Twig/Autoloader.php";

        Twig_Autoloader::register();
        $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../views/templates');
        $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
            'cache' => '../views/cache',
        ));
    }

    
    public function index()
    {   
        $user = new User();
        $resulset = $user->getAll();

        $data = array("usersList" => $resulset);

        echo $twig->render('index.twig.php', $data);
    }

}
```

Y este ya es el que carga la vista.

El problema que tengo es que no me encuentra la clase IndexController.php y tengo sospechas de que es debido al nombre de espacio.

Este es mi archivo `composer.json:

```html
{
    "name": "diego/pruebamvc",
    "type": "project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "diegodenavas",
            "email": "diegodenavas@hotmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Src\\": "Src/"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Y éste mi árbol de directorios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? ¿Cómo debo llamar al namespace y donde? Y me surge una duda, si el autoloader es util para no tener que estar haciendo includes y requires de cada archivo? No pierde esa utilidad el tener que estar importando cada clase con "use"?

Comment: ya ha ejecutado  `composer dump`?

Comment: Si, ya está ejecutado

Comment: No necesitas requerir el autoload en la definición de clases ni en los constructores de clases, sino en los scripts donde vayas a usar una clase. Y si quieres evitar `use ...` puedes poner la ruta completa de la clase: `Src\Libs\FrontController::main();` No sé si el uso de `Src` dé problemas, pero en la convención de nombre habitual se suele usar `App` o el nombre de tu aplicación en lugar de `Src`